# HTACCESS: Download File as Another Filename via Browser

Tags: .htaccess, zip

I need some help. How can I do this stuff , downloading using htaccess. 
I want this way.

Current URL:

https://example.com/comp/test1.zip

to be

https://example.com/comp/Archive.zip

where Archive.zip is a static value

Comment: Which url exists on your server? The first or the second one?

Comment: @starkeen the 1st one

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite **/comp/Archive.zip** to **/comp/test1.zip** .

Try this in your /root/.htaccss

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^comp/Archive\.zip$ /comp/test1.zip [L,NC]
```